# Create bar graph from Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, bar-chart

I've column of data in excel like this;
[image]

Now I want to create bar graph with count of data in ranges. Like count of data in range `1-2 2-3 3-4 4-5`.

> I'm a newbie in excel and totally stuck here. Anyone guide me what
>   should I do to achieve result?

Comment: I.e. you are trying to create a histogram?

Comment: yes....I want to create a histogram..

Comment: [Create a histogram](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-histogram-85680173-064b-4024-b39d-80f17ff2f4e8)

Comment: Histogram shows graph with provided data.. but I want to range it manually from 1-2 2-3 3-4 and so on to a specific number..

Comment: Then you can use the Analysis Tool-Pak add-in, specifying your bins in a bin range.

Comment: After you create the histogram, click on your axis, and on the right panel, under "axis options", you can manually change your bin ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the Histogram functionality of the Analysis Tool-Pak add-in that comes bundled with Excel.

As referenced by [MSFT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-histogram-85680173-064b-4024-b39d-80f17ff2f4e8) for Excel versions 2007-2013 (but still available for later versions):

1. Make sure you have loaded the Analysis ToolPak.
2. Add the input data in one column (which you already have) and your bins in another.
3. Click **Data** > **Data Analysis**.
4. Click **Histogram** > **OK**.
5. Under **Input**, use the **Input Range** box for your cells with data and the **Bin Range** box for your cells with the bins.
6. Click **Chart Ouput**.